# Can we do a systemcall in a systemtap probe?

Tags: systemtap

For example, given

```
probe syscall.pwrite {

}
```

Can I do a pread in the probe of pwrite?

Thanks!

Erben

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** normally do things like call kernel or userspace functions from a systemtap probe handler, because it is not safe to do so.  (Probes may fire from contexts where very few operations may be safe.)  This is why probe handlers normally run atomic, brief, non-intrusive operations.

See the embedded-C section in the manual or examples to see how to escape from the normal safety sandbox.  You must take responsibility for safety and security, and handle technical details like writing C code that calls the routine of interest.